# Error resolving plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '8.1.1', apply: false] > You must specify a URL for a Maven repository

Tags: java, android, kotlin, maven, gradle

I am LovelyBlitz, today I try to study developing Android softwares with Android Studio, but when I choose the "empty activity", IDE reports this error message:***"Error resolving plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '8.1.1', apply: false] > You must specify a URL for a Maven repository."***
I tried every solution but it still cannot be solved now. Could you help me ? Thanks for your help ^v^

1. environment: gradle8.3; Android Studio Giraffe; openJDK 17; Windows 11 22H2
2. the error message:
   Error resolving plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '8.1.1', apply: false] You must specify a URL for a Maven repository.
3. the code of build.gradle.kts:

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.1.1" apply false
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

val sourceCompatibility by extra(11)
val sourceCompatibility1 by extra(JavaVersion.VERSION_21)
val targetCompatibility by extra(JavaVersion.VERSION_21)
val sourceCompatibility2 by extra(JavaVersion.VERSION_21)
```

4. the code of settings.gradle.kts

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        maven { "https://maven.aliyun.com/repository/public/" }
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        maven {
            "https://maven.aliyun.com/repository/public";
            "https://maven.aliyun.com/repository/central";
            "https://maven.aliyun.com/repository/gradle-plugin/"
        }
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.name = "HelloWorld"
include(":app")
```

I have tried add url to "maven", like this :
`maven { url 'https://maven.aliyun.com/repository/public' }`
but it not works.